# create list of widgets of n length where n is set by another widget

Tags: python-3.x, ipywidgets

I want to have the output of the size widget determine the number of widgets created in the output of the `return_widgets` function. The code below works to a point, but does not update when the value of the `intslider` changes.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
def return_widgets(size):
    return [widgets.IntText(value=x) for x in range(size)]

size = widgets.IntSlider(value=3, min=0, max=5, step=1, description='size:')
w = return_widgets(size.value)
widgets.VBox([size, *w])
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this, not sure it's a very good solution but kind of works:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

def return_widgets(size):
    return [widgets.IntText(value=x) for x in range(size)]

out = widgets.Output()
def on_value_change(change):
    out.clear_output()
    with out:
       w = return_widgets(change['new'])
       display(*w)

size = widgets.IntText(value=3, min=1, max=5, description='size')

size.observe(on_value_change, 'value')
widgets.VBox([size, out])
```